# Full text search with Sails.js

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

Is full text search possible with Sails.js and/or Waterline?

I know PostgreSQL supports full text search, but it doesn't look like the PostgreSQL adaptor for Waterline supports that feature as far as I can tell.

Would an efficient full text search be possible with Waterline's `contains` helper method?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
Model.find({ class: { 'like': '%history%' }})
```

Which, according to the documentation, is akin to this:

```
Model.find({ class: { 'contains': 'history' }})
```

It would be good for you to give an example of what you are attempting, codewise.